# Virtual, how to use it?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual

```
class a
{
    public:
        a(int);    
        virtual ~a();
        virtual void print();
        int getNumber()
    private:
        int number;
};

class b : public a
{
    public:
        b(int);
        virtual ~b();
};

class c : public b
{
    public:
        c(int);
        virtual ~c();
        virtual void print();
};
```

those are headers that represent a cpp file. I implemented all the methods in each appropriate cpp file.
I used this code and it works just fine although I wonder if class b should also implemented 
print (even like that : print(){}), because it seems to me of better programming.
so what is the appropriate way to do it ?
implement (even if not necessary) or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only write the functions that are going to be overloaded by the subclass.  If the subclass is not specializing a given behavior, then it would be bad practice to write a copy of a parent function in the subclass.  Not only would this be wasteful and potentially confusing, it could also lead to errors at some point later on.

Consider this: a parent class I'll call Monkey and a subclass I'll call Tarzan.  In the Monkey class, I'll define a function for Swing().

Now, since Tarzan is a derivative of Monkey and learned to swing in the trees like Monkey, there's no need to write Tarzan's own version of the Swing function.  But, let's say that I did write it anyway just to be "complete."  Now I've got 2 routines to update if I need to change the way a Monkey swings: one for the Monkey class and another for Tarzan.  Worse yet, if I DO change how a Monkey will Swing and *forget* to make the same change in Tarzan, Tarzan will no longer swing like a Monkey and THAT would be unexpected and probably wrong.

Conclusion: only write code in subclass functions where the subclass requires specialization from what is already defined for the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of inheritance in object-oriented programming is that you can rely on the superclass implementation of methods you don't want to have to rewrite.